# Can ANOVA be used for percent frequency data?

Tags: anova, independence

**Problem:** Suppose there are three restaurants in a town. I conduct a survey by asking each person what percentage of time you eat in restaurant A, restaurant B and restaurant C. The percentages for each person sum to 100%. I am interested whether there is a difference between restaurants with regard to frequency people eat there.

**Question:** Can I run 1-way repeated measure ANOVA? My contemplation is that values of restaurant C = 100 - restaurant A - restaurant B (so, they are not independent). If it's a problem, should I instead run non-parametric test?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, strictly speaking,  we cannot apply ANOVA in this case. ANOVA requires three conditions - independence, normality and equivariance. If you compromise on the independence part, you are tampering with the distribution of the test statistic as it is no longer F-distribution.

However, you can do the following: Get the following variables A-B, B-C and C-A. Now, run 3 individual t-tests where the null hypothesis is the difference is zero and the alternate hypothesis is the difference is not zero.

Comment: Thanks. So you propose to run the ANOVA on differences. But how it can be that these differences are independent while the original data is not ?

Comment: Well, I am not saying that A-B is independent of B-C. But, within A-B, all the values are independent of one another.

Comment: Oh.. wait, I suggest to run t-tests, NOT ANOVA on these three sets of A-B, B-C  and C-A separately.

Comment: Ah... Ok I see. In a pair-wise, they are independent. Thanks

Comment: If you are satisfied, please upvote, accept and close this thread. Thank you.

Comment: Is it OK now? (I never did it before)